# Parsing through nested hash using .present? - undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, hash

***EDITED 2nd time to show that I need to handle looking in multiple locations.

**EDITED to show exception being raise even when handler built in.**

I am currently parsing through responses from an API that includes arrays that I've converted into a hash using

```
hash_table = xml_response.to_h
```

The challenge is that sometimes the data I'm looking for is located in different locations, and when I use a key method:

```
data_i_need = hash_table['key1']['key2'][0]
```

if there's nothing there, it throws this error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I've tried using:

```
if hash_table['key1']['key2'][0].present?
   data_i_need = hash_table['key1']['key2'][0]
   puts "data was here"
elsif hash_table['key3']['key4'][0].present?
   data_i_need = hash_table['key3']['key4'][0]
   puts "data here"
elsif hash_table['key5']['key6'][0].present?
   data_i_need = hash_table['key5']['key6'][0]
   puts "data here"
else 
   "data not found"
end
```

But it throws the same error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Have you considered working directly with the XML using Nokogiri and XPath? Might be easier than trying to walk through a bunch of nested Hashes.

Comment: I'd be happy to if it were easier.

Answer (score 0):

you should check for the presence all the previous hash key because if one of them is nil, the exception will be raised

```
hash_table['key1'].present? && hash_table['key1']['key2'].present? && hash_table['key1']['key2']['key3'].present? && hash_table['key1']['key2']['key3'][0].present?
```

Update:
To return "not found", you can catch the exception like this:

```
data_i_need = begin 
  hash_table['key1']['key2']['key3'][0] 
rescue NoMethodError
  "data not found" 
end
```

Update 2:
You can use this function to check if the keys exist in the hash in the if else condition statements:

```
h = {:a => {:b => {0 => 1}}, :c => 2}

def has_nested_keys?(hash, *keys)
  keys.inject(hash) do |result, key|
    result = result[key]
  end  
  true
rescue 
  false
end

has_nested_keys?(h, :a, :b, 0) #=> true
has_nested_keys?(h, :c, :d, 0) #=> false
```

Comment: Hi Vu - I am realizing I should have clarified that even in the case above (edited) where I introduce logic, it still raises the exception.

Comment: If it doesn't find it, I need it to look elsewhere.  If it can't find it anywhere, I need it to tell me "not found" and move on.

Comment: In that case, you can try this: 
data_i_need = begin
  hash_table['key1']['key2']['key3'][0]
rescue 
  "data not found"
end

Comment: How is rescue implemented with the if and elsif logic?  In other words, where would I insert rescue here?:  

    if hash_table['key1']['key2'].present?
    data_i_need = hash_table['key1']['key2']
    elsif hash_table['key3']['key4'].present?
    data_i_need = hash_table['key3']['key4']
etc...

Comment: Please check the updated answer above, rescue will catch the error that you got when one of the key doesnt exist and return "data not found" in those cases

Comment: That catches the error when one key location doesn't exist. But how can that be integrated when looking in 4 different locations?

Comment: How would that work when the syntax of my hash keys are as follows? 

response_hashed['ItemSearchResponse']['Items']['Item'][0]['ASIN'])

Comment: The function use splat operator so that it work with any number of arguments. You can call has_nested_keys(response_hashed, 'ItemSearchResponse', 'Items', 'Item', 0, 'ASIN')